# Postfix SMTP server rejects password for outgoing only

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

I've had postfix working on my server for a while now and have sent emails out from it, my server recently crashed and everything came back fine except I can't send emails anymore, it says the server rejected the password.

Incoming still works fine with the same password and I've run out of ideas of what could be wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Incoming" has nothing to do with Postfix, but with you IMAP/POP3 server.

I guess you have SASL authorization for sending emails. Is your saslauth daemon running?

Take a look at your log files and try to go through the common list of problems that are explained [here](http://www.julian-seifert.de/?p=5).